# What's the bug here in my python3 code?

Tags: python-3.x

I have been trying to make a timer that rings lately in python3 on mac. All is good before I ran into this bug. Here's my code below:

```
import time
import pygame, sys

while True:
   uin = input(">> ")
   try:
       when_to_stop = abs(int(uin))
   except KeyboardInterrupt:
       break
   except:
       print("Not a number!")

   while when_to_stop >= 0:
       m, s = divmod(when_to_stop, 60)
       h, m = divmod(m, 60)
       time_left = str(h).zfill(2) + ":" + str(m).zfill(2) + ":" + str(s).zfill(2)
    print(time_left, "\r", end="")
    time.sleep(1)
    when_to_stop -= 1
print()
print('Times Up!')
display_width = 640
display_height = 480
screen=pygame.display.set_mode([display_width, display_height])
pygame.time.delay(1000)
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
soundwav=pygame.mixer.Sound("/Users/user/Desktop/Clock-ringing.wav")
soundwav.play()
while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
```

I got this error when I pressed the close button on pygame window:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/countdown.py", line 37, in <module>
    sys.exit()
SystemExit
```

Can anyone please tell me the reason?

Comment: normal behaviour

Comment: But how do I close the pygame window??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal behaviour. `sys.exit()` always throws an exception. use `pygame.quit()` instead.

Comment: Still doesn't work, throws me a error and pygame will freeze after I clicked close. This is the error: 

'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "countdown.py", line 35, in <module>
    for event in pygame.event.get():
pygame.error: video system not initialized'